# Where to Write Shared Application Data -Between Users in OSX

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I understand that I need to store data in `~/Library/Application Support/YourApp` for current user or `/Library/Application Support/YourApp` for shared users.

But it seems I need to get `root` access to write data to `/Library/Application Support/YourApp`.. right?

Can I write to `Users/Shared` ,Does this required `root` privileges?
Is there anything wrong in doing this?