# How to get URL of /Users/Shared/

Tags: swift, macos

How can I get the URL of `/Users/Shared/` directory using SWIFT?

I can get URL of Application Support for the current user Like this

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
```

Comment: no. you can't there are no such api like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 let sharedFolderURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .userDirectory, 
                                                    in: .localDomainMask, 
                                                    appropriateFor: nil, 
                                                    create: false)
                            .appendingPathComponent("Shared", isDirectory: true)
```

**Edit:**

As no dynamic path component is involved you can even write

```
let sharedFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Shared")
```

---

But `/Users/Shared` is not a good solution to avoid a helper app to be able to write in `/Library/Application Support` with elevated privileges.

Comment: Thanks.This the problem I'm trying to solve https://stackoverflow.com/q/46704121/848968 Is getting elevated privilage a complex task for an application that is  designed to run without elevated prilviages.

Comment: Getting elevated privileges is not a complex task but it's quite tricky to implement.

Comment: Will the shared folder be present on old versions of OSX that support Swift

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember `/Users/Shared` exists in all versions of macOS